# Is there any way to trace the execution in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++

I am a Beginner in **OMNET++** and I need to trace my code step by step, but the framework convert the tracing to assembly code. is there any way to trace the code step by step?
or at least make the program executed until reaching particular line?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you build your code in debug mode, i.e. select *debug* as the active configuration in the IDE.